# How browser delete session or delete history works?

Tags: php, session, browser, cookies, cross-browser

Let a user using Mozilla browser ,  On three tabs he  login to his yahoo account ,gmail and hotmail.
Now if we Clear Recent History , all three session will be cleared.

But at the same time if there is another session in any another browser it will not be cleared.

So What i am trying to ask here is , the  cookies and session related details ,browser  cache  will be in the local computer and it will be cleared on clearing history.

But is it browser specific?
The cookie and all will have any browser specific id , how it will differentiate that now clear the IE history or clear chrome history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact use two different accounts on two different browsers at the same time. The browser history/cookies etc are specific to the browser in question.

There isn't a "standard" where browser save their settings, each do it as they file. MSIE might use the Windows Registry while Firefox might use a local database file.

Comment: How it is specific and how it is maintained is the question?

Comment: The web browser saves cookies in a file, specific to the browser. This is outright obvious.

Comment: Where ? can we see that in our local system ? in any folder??

Comment: @Zod, sure. Let's talk about Firefox. Firefox has a system called profiles. A profile is like a user account. The "profile" has a file called cookies.sqlite, which contain the current cookies. My current profile is here: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` there should be at least one folder in there, just open it and inside you should see several cookie files.

Answer (score 2):

For the server to keep track of a client session a session id is sent to the client. Which the client uses in each request to the server.

On the local computer each browser has it's own way of saving the cookie files. So when you clear the cookies in Firefox, then the cookies saved by Firefox will be deleted. Same thing with Chrome, IE, Safari etc.

They could even be using a own way of serializing the cookies for all that I know.

Comment: Ancide - Although that is possible, that's not how cookies work (as far as I know). A session ID is saved in cookies and the browser simply provides them back. The server doesn't check the browser type, just the cookie the browser has presented.

Comment: Alright, so what you are saying is that if we have 2 requests to the server from the same ip which doesn't have a session id, the server won't check if it's from the same browser? Just provide a new session id for each?

Comment: @ancide you saying about how server know . i think my question  is related to local system and browser. How session and cookie are specific to any browser and how it is maintained is the question?

Comment: @Ancide - Yes. I'm not saying no one checks (or can check) the browser type, I'm just saying in general they don't check the browser type.

Comment: On clearing session , no activity related to server is happening , as per my understanding. local id and values will be cleared.!!

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Yeah, I get the concept. They don't check the browser type when performing the session id yielding. But thanks for clearing that up for me, I'll edit my answer! :)